# In-App-Purchase Error while testing in Sandbox Environment

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to test In app purchase products in sandbox environment whose status is Waiting for review (i'm getting these products as invalid while i'm trying to test them in sandbox environment). I was getting the same products as valid when the status of my IAP products was Ready to submit & the application status was In Review. Currently my app status is waiting for upload as it was rejected citing some guidelines issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently have an app in *Waiting for Review* state and can still test In App Purchases. Those IAP have been submitted for review together with the app itself.

Nevertheless I had an issue with IAP (invalid product ids) which resolved itself only by removing the app from the device and reinstalling it. This was device specific because while it occured on one device a second device was working fine.

Comment: thanks a ton marcus i was able able to resolve it. But now i'm getting the following error while i'm trying to make a purchase :Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x281670 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}. Can u suggest me what could be going wrong.

Comment: i resolved this error by logging out of iTunes store in setting's